# Angular ng-select: GroupBy array ng-select

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

Hi i have a problem with my ng-select, in this case storeTypes is an array, if storeTypeswould be an string there functionality has been perfect, but I nees that this variable are an string[]. What can I do?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
             
        <label>Grouping</label>
        <ng-select [items]="accounts"
                bindLabel="label"
                bindValue="code"
                groupBy="storeTypes[0]"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount">
        </ng-select>
        `
})
export class AppComponent {

    selectedAccount = '9'
    accounts = [
        {code: "9", checked: false, label: "Adidas", storeTypes:["Store"]},
        {code: "91", checked: false, label: "Nike", storeTypes:["Store"]},
        {code: "92", checked: false, label: "5guys", storeTypes:["Restaurant"]},
        {code: "93", checked: false, label: "McDonal", storeTypes:["Restaurant"]},
        {code: "94", checked: false, label: "FastFood", storeTypes:["Restaurant"]}
   ];
   
    constructor() {
    }
    
}
```

Raw now i see that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfmAL.png)

I need this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Z98.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is **groupby** should be **[groupby]**.
Secondly, you should create a helper function to group as groupby will either take property name or a function.

Try below:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
             
        <label>Grouping</label>
        <ng-select [items]="accounts"
                bindLabel="label"
                bindValue="code"
                [groupBy]="groupingHelper"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount">
        </ng-select>
        `
})
export class AppComponent {

    groupingHelper(item){return item.storeTypes[0]}
    selectedAccount = '9'
    accounts = [
        {code: "9", checked: false, label: "Adidas", storeTypes:["Store"]},
        {code: "91", checked: false, label: "Nike", storeTypes:["Store"]},
        {code: "92", checked: false, label: "5guys", storeTypes:["Restaurant"]},
        {code: "93", checked: false, label: "McDonal", storeTypes:["Restaurant"]},
        {code: "94", checked: false, label: "FastFood", storeTypes:["Restaurant"]}
   ];
   
    constructor() {
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Great that it worked for you! You can accept it as answer so it will be helpful for others too.